# No data is transferred from the form to the controller

Tags: java, spring

I do not receive data. In html I transfer the list of products. Then I display each element and put a button under it. When you click on the button, the product ID should be transferred to the controller

part of `catalog.html`

```
              <th:block th:each="prod : ${products}">
                  <div>
                      <span th:text="${prod.getId()}">  </span>
                      <br>
                      <span th:text="${prod.getName()}">  </span>
                      <br>
                      <span th:text="${prod.getPrice()}">  </span>
                      <br>
                      <span th:text="${prod.getImg()}">  </span>
                      <br>
                  </div>
                  <div class="button-group" sec:authorize="isFullyAuthenticated()">
                      <form name="time" action="/catalog" method="post">
                          <input type="hidden" th:id="product" th:name="product" th:value="*{prod.id}">
                          <input type="submit">
                      </form>
                  </div>
              </th:block>
           </div>
```

`Controller`

```
   @PostMapping
    public ModelAndView createOrder(@ModelAttribute("product") Product product) {
        System.out.println(product.getId());
          ---///---
```

Comment: Convert `@PostMapping` to `@PostMapping("/catalog")`

Comment: did not work,  i has ```@RequestMapping("/catalog")```

Comment: Is it a spring boot application or spring mvc application?